# Create an AKS Cluster that has Helm 2 Installed

Tags: kubernetes-helm, azure-container-service

Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS) recently upgraded to Helm 3.  I love what Helm 3 brings to the table and am excited to use it.

But much of the tooling out there (namely Jenkins X) is not ready for Helm 3.

Is there a command line option to make an AKS cluster that is using Helm 2?

Comment: Do you try to init helm again?

Answer (score 0):

You can use both helm 2 and helm 3 with AKS. You can still use helm 2 with AKS if you initiate the helm init command from a helm 2 client on an AKS cluster.

The commands to follow in that case would be:

```
az aks create -g MyResourceGroup -n MyCluster

az aks get-credentials -g MyResourceGroup -n MyCluster

kubectl config get-contexts // Gets the kubernetes contexts present locally
kubectl config use-context <context-name-for-aks-cluster>

// Install helm 2 if not already installed before proceeding with helm init
helm init
```